# SQL error while using LIMIT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner with SQL and I'm following the tutorial at [W3 Schools SQL Exercises](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp). I tried to run the following query but I am getting error:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers LIMIT 5, 5
```

**ERROR:**

> Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: Do your database have a table named Customers?

Comment: @Macro: Yes, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp

Comment: Maybe a stupid question. But what db are you using?. "Limit" is used by MySql while in sql server you use "Top"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using MySql syntax instead of SqlServer syntax.
You should use:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Customers
```

Comment: But I actually need just one of them. Like I need the 5th tuple. How do i get that?

Comment: You have to use Row_Number. Look at this article http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you're following the example in the link you provided...

> We will use the Customers table in the Northwind database:

*Northwind* is a sample database in MS SQL products. And MS SQL does not have support using `LIMIT` queries. So that website is probably using some version of that RDBMS.

Try running:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM customers;
```

This gets you the first 5 records in the result set (unordered). It does not skip any records, though, as your `LIMIT 5, 5` clause would have.

Comment: But given that there is no `ORDER BY` anyway and so `ORDER` is undefined you might as well just imagine that it has skipped 5 arbitrary records as the only time it will make a difference is if the table has between 5-10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that they use ADODB, so you should use TOP clause:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to use [`offset`](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/queries-limit.html):

`select * from Customers limit 5 offset 5;`

Not all RDBMSs support the `limit m,n` syntax (I believe MySQL does, but PostgreSQL doesn't).  Also, you'll probably want to use an `order by` clause to help ensure that you get consistent results with your query (because databases, in general, don't care about the order of rows or columns unless you specify):

```
select * from Customers order by col limit 5 offset 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can use `rownum`:

```
select * from Customers where rownum < 6;
```